Dynamic Soql query for a multiselect picklist
Test Data inserted:
Record1->Id = '012xxxxxxxxxxxx', Group__c = 'Assistant;Attorney;Builder Client'
Record2->Id = '012yyyyyyyyyyyy', Group__c = 'Appraiser;Builder'

String searchValue = 'Builder';
String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name, Email, Group__c ' +
    'FROM Contact ' +
    'WHERE Group__c INCLUDES (\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchValue) + '\') LIMIT 501';

List<Contact> contacts = Database.query(queryString);
System.debug('Queried Contacts: ' + contacts);

Here i am getting only the record with Id '012yyyyyyyyyyyy'. Where am I going wrong? Depending on the includes string i have to add in the dynamic operator map. Please let me know which one is correct?
'MultiSelect-Contains'   => ' {0} INCLUDES (\'{1}\') '

'MultiSelect-Contains' => ' {0} INCLUDES ({1}) '


Thankyou Mariia.

Builder is not the same value as Builder Client.  If you want to query for the search term if it appears anywhere withn the string, then you should use LIKE, not INCLUDES.
WHERE Group__c LIKE '%Builder%'


Thanks David. I just confirmed to my PO about this limitation involved with INCLUDES.
